# Variables Not Being Placed in Email Body

Tags: mql4

I have set out a load of variables which are to be sent out in an informational (is that even a word? It should be a word ;)) email when a position is executed.

Everything works as programmed and an email is indeed sent when a position has been successfully filled by the broker.

However, despite correctly declaring my variables, I'm getting blank spaces in my email where the variables should be.

The `GlobalNamespace.mqh` file initially declares the variables and sets them as string variables.
The EA (which, by the way, calls the `GlobalNamespace.mqh` file) and assigns each variable with MQL4's functions. The EA then passes control to the file containing the `SendMail()` Statement.

The file containing the `SendMail()` statement also calls the `GlobalNamespace.mqh` file in order to determine that they are string variables, and sends the email but without the variables.

I don't see any reason whatsoever as to why there are blank spaces where these variables should be placed in the email body, as they are correctly initialised and the appropriate #include files are ...well, included.

Why is MetaEditor refusing go play ball?

It makes no sense.

My `MQH` `GlobalNamespace.mqh` file is as follows:

```
string            ExecutionPrice;
string            ExecutionTimeframe;
string            ExecutionSymbol;
```

My `MQL` File (EA) is as follows

```
#include <GlobalNamespace.mqh>

void OnTick(){
//---
   //Data pertaining to the executed position.
   ExecutionSymbol              =  Symbol();
   ExecutionTimeframe       =  IntegerToString(Period()/60,0);
   ExecutionPrice               =  DoubleToString(OrderOpenPrice(),Digits);

   if(......){

    <Run SendMail.mqh>

   }

 //---
}
```

This is the MQH file `SendMail.mqh` which sends the email upon an event:

```
#include <GlobalNamespace.mqh>

SendMail("<subject>,"Symbol"+ExecutionSymbol+"  Price"+ExecutionPrice+"  Timeframe"+ExecutionTimeframe);
```

These variables are used in a number of files, therefore I do not wish to declare them locally.

Bypassing the EA when declaring the global variables